# How can I add more files to the precach manifest list?

Tags: workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

My app is created using `create-react-app` and I'm using `react-app-rewired` to change the `navigationFallback: "index.html"` to `navigationFallback: "offline.html"`.

I use the `copy-web-plugin` to copy the file `offline.html` into the dist folder. However, this is file is not found in the `precach-manifest` file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Workbox v5 and above supports an [`additionalManifestEntries` property](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-webpack-plugin.GenerateSW#GenerateSW) that allows you to add in extra precache manifest entries.

But Workbox v5 also generates its default precache manifest list based on the entire set of `webpack` assets for a given compilation, including anything that was added via `copy-webpack-plugin`.  So you probably wouldn't have to use `additionalManifestEntries` if you upgraded.